# Batch file not moving files properly

Tags: windows-10, batch, batch-file

I created a batch program on Windows 7 a few months ago. Its basic purpose is to organize the things I download into different folders in the libraries, based on the file type, then open Windows Media Player (so my media can be accessed by my Xbox360). After upgrading to Windows 10 the batch file has completely stopped working - instead of moving files, all it does is spit back errors saying `access is denied`. Even though the file structure has been untouched. The code is as follows.

```
   echo Organizing Your Videos . . .
        move *.mp4 C:\Users\Devon\Videos
    echo Your Videos have been Organized!
    echo Organizing Your Images . . .
    move *.jpg C:\Users\Devon\Pictures\
    move *.bmp C:\Users\Devon\Pictures\
    move *.gif C:\Users\Devon\Pictures\
    move *.png C:\Users\Devon\Pictures\
    move *.PNG C:\Users\Devon\Pictures\
echo Your images Have Been Organized!
echo ORGANIZATION PROTOCOL COMPLETE!!!
    echo Starting Windows Media Player ...
    echo Waiting 5 Seconds ...
        timeout 5
        start wmplayer.exe
```

I'm 99% sure this is some kind of syntax error but I'm not sure how to fix it or if I'm doing this right.
EDIT: This is a picture of the error I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the user running the batch file is user `Devon` and that this user has _still_ **write permission** to the current directory _and_ the target directories?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli is correct. The user running the batch file must either be an Administrator, or have the `privilege` to **R**ead **W**rite and e**X**ecute. BOTH within the `\Devon` folder, as well as the ability to execute (run) the application `wmplayer.exe`. Just another thought; Does the user `Devon` still exist after the upgrade? Have any of the permissions changed on that account after the upgrade? You should check.

Comment: I'd replace `C:\Users\Devon` by `%UserProfile%`...

Comment: yes i tried that found out that apperently permissions didnt transfer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're moving files from your Downloads folder, I would write it as this:

```
@echo off

set "dwn=%USERPROFILE%\Downloads"
set "pic=%USERPROFILE%\Pictures"
set "vid=%USERPROFILE%\Videos"

echo Organizing Your Videos . . .
for /r "%dwn%" %%A in (*.mp4) do (move /y "%%A" "%vid%" >nul)
echo.
echo           Your Videos have been Organized!
echo.
echo Organizing Your Images . . .
for /r "%dwn%" %%B in (*.jpg *.bmp *.gif *.png) do (move /y "%%B" "%pic%" >nul)
echo.
echo           Your Images have been Organized!
echo.
echo            _
echo           /(^|
echo          (  :
echo         __\  \  _____
echo       (____)  `^|
echo      (____)^|   ^|
echo       (____).__^|
echo        (___)__.^|_____
echo.
echo ORGANIZATION PROTOCOL COMPLETE!!!
echo.
echo Starting Windows Media Player . . .
echo.
echo Waiting 5 seconds . . .
timeout 5 >nul
start wmplayer.exe
```

the `for /r` loops through all files in a directory - it seems excessive when you only have one video file type, but you can see how the pictures get handled by one line; you can do the same thing for other video types as required. I spaced things out with my own personal preference and for some reason I feel like you would appreciate the flair of having a thumbs-up, so I spent more time on that than I did writing the code - since I have a really good sense of priority. I always prefer variables when they can clean things up and prevent you from having to change paths in several different lines. The `%USERPROFILE%` environment variable is also best practice if you're working within the profile your script is modifying - which you are. Note that with `%USERPROFILE%`, if you run this script as admin from an account that does not have admin, it will work in/modify the admin's user profile instead.

Also note that file extensions are not case sensitive, so I removed the `.PNG`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the directory environment your cmd script is running in.

It is running in `c:\Windows\System32`

So its trying to move system files instead of files from your downloads.

Change the script to explicitly have the path to your download folder and it should work just fine

```
 echo Organizing Your Videos . . .
    move C:\Users\Devon\Downloads\*.mp4 C:\Users\Devon\Videos
  echo Your Videos have been Organized!
  echo Organizing Your Images . . .
  move C:\Users\Devon\Downloads\*.jpg C:\Users\Devon\Pictures\
  move C:\Users\Devon\Downloads\*.bmp C:\Users\Devon\Pictures\
  move C:\Users\Devon\Downloads\*.gif C:\Users\Devon\Pictures\
  move C:\Users\Devon\Downloads\*.png C:\Users\Devon\Pictures\
  move C:\Users\Devon\Downloads\*.PNG C:\Users\Devon\Pictures\
 echo Your images Have Been Organized!
 echo ORGANIZATION PROTOCOL COMPLETE!!!
 echo Starting Windows Media Player ...
 echo Waiting 5 Seconds ...
    timeout 5
    start wmplayer.exe
```

Although really you should use the User profile variable in place of the path on both sides to be future-proof